# Property/ function to find empty subreports and hide them in Access report

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

How can I tell if a subreport is empty? Is there a property or function I can use to check whether there is any data in the subreport? I want to write a subroutine that says

```
If IsEmpty(subreport) Then
    subreport.Visible = False
Else
    subreport.Visible = True
End If
```

That, combined with making the subreport small and allowing CanGrow would help me display only the values that do exist without taking up space on my report if the subreport is empty. Ideally, I'd also be able to hide the label of the subreport if it's empty.

Comment: See https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=212478.

Answer (score 0):

If the VBA code is going to be on the main report then you would use,

```
Me.subreport.Report.RecordsetClone.RecordCount
```

to get the number of records. If the code is in the sub-report then you only have to write,

```
Me.RecordsetClone.RecordCount
```

If you have any issues with this or need an explanation leave a comment and I'll get back to you.

Comment: You can also test `Me.subreport.Report.HasData`.

Comment: You can only read from that when the report is in Print Preview as far as I know.

Comment: According to [Report.HasData property (Access)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.report.hasdata) it can be read while printing or in print preview. It would have to be checked in the `Format` event of the report section containing the subreport. It could also be checked in the subreport itself to let it hide its own headers and footers.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I would need the property to be readable in report view, not just print preview/ print. I tried adding the following if statement to the subreport `If IsNull(Me.RecordsetClone.RecordCount) Then
    Me.Visible = False
Else
    Me.Visible = True
End If` and it is working to hide empty subreports in print preview, but not in report view.

Comment: Use `If Me.RecordsetClone.RecordCount = 0 Then` instead of `IsNull()` as and empty subreport will return `0`, not `Null`

Comment: Or simply `Me.Visible = Me.RecordsetClone.RecordCount > 0`

Comment: I changed to `=0` rather than `IsNull()`  but I am still having the issue that the empty subreport is only invisible in print preview mode, not in report mode.